# Mysql in Array select with specific property for each element in array?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to optimize my code and I can't quite figure out
if what I am trying is a viable approach, or I should check something
else out, and I hope you could help me out a bit.

So basically I have a Mysql select which is similar to this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as book_orders 
FROM book_sales 
WHERE book_number = ? 
AND purchase_date > ? (timestamp)
```

I have a list with bookNumbers and matching pruchaseDates and right now,
I am sending a Select for each number, which sounds unnecessary because
in theory, could create a list and be done with all of them with 1 select.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM book_sales 
WHERE book_number IN (1,2,3,4) 
AND purchase_date > ? 
GROUP BY book_number
```

With a purchase_date set, it will filter all the book_sales according to the purchase_date, but I would like to filter each element in the List to a specific date like this:

```
book_number => 1 purchase_date => 1412
book_number => 2 purchase_date => 1621
book_number => 3 purchase_date => 1014
book_number => 4 purchase_date => 1978
```

I tried a Subquery like the one shown, but it is too low and can't handle much data

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM book_sales WHERE book_number = 1 AND purchase_date > 1412) AS bk1,
    ....
    ...
```

Comment: Please provide show create table , some insert data and your expected result

Comment: You may use separate conditions pairs combined with OR `WHERE (book_number = 1 AND purchase_date > 1412) OR (book_number = 2 AND purchase_date > 1621) OR ...`. Alternatively you may save you criteria pairs into temptable and join it by according expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save you criteria pairs into temptable and join it:

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp (  book_number INT 
                            , purchase_date INT
         -- define PK only if the amount of pairs is over 10 - it can improve
         --                 , PRIMARY KEY (book_number, purchase_date)
                           ) ENGINE = Memory
SELECT 1 book_number, 1412 purchase_date UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1621
SELECT 3, 1014
SELECT 4, 1978;
```

and then

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM book_sales
JOIN tmp ON book_sales.book_number = tmp.book_number
        AND book_sales.purchase_date > tmp.purchase_date;
```

Or do the same using CTE if MySQL version allows.